# .NET producing wrong version for my Operating System

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, .net-core

I am trying to enable http3 support in my .net web app.

In my program.cs I want to check that the OS is Windows 11 which is what I am running. However .NET seems to think otherwise - shown below. I am using the System.Environment api to access the OSVersion.

```
OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
```

When I inspect my os object I am seeing these values for the properties:

Platform = Win32NT

VersionString = "Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.22621.0"

Version = {10.0.22621.0}

Should this not be shown as Microsoft Windows NT 11.x.x.x ?

It is not a problem I need to solve, I don't NEED to enable http3 but I am curious why I am seeing Windows 10...

Comment: Wiki: The Windows 11 2022 Update[90] (also known as version 22H2[91][92] and codenamed "Sun Valley 2") is the first and current major update to Windows 11. It carries the build number 10.0.22621. Similar question to take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69038560/detect-windows-11-with-net-framework-or-windows-api

Comment: (there are preview channels you can opt into; I'm currently running 10.0.23565.0 on the "dev" channel - channels are "release", "beta", "dev" and "canary", in increasing freshness+risk) - ultimately, though: are you seeing a problem, other than the string saying 10 rather than 11? if so: what is the problem that you are seeing?

Comment: It's long been recommended by Microsoft that you use *feature* detection, not heuristics based on version numbers.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!